# Flask Logging Manager not working, client not setting the cookies

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cookies, session-cookies

**Issue:** I'm trying to use LoginManager to manage user sessions, but it seems that my frontend is not saving the cookie on the client side.

**Context:**

The initial page hits /login which authenticates the users, and setts it using loging_user. The front end then triggers /get_user/.  but that route is protected by @login_required, which returns a 401 error.

I believe the client side should have used a cookie to validate the user, but I don't see it on the browser.

create_app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='',
            static_folder='frontend/build/static', template_folder='frontend/build/templates')
db_uri = os.environ.get('LUNCHROULETTE_URI')

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_uri

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

app.py

```
#other imports
from create_app import app, db

# Initialize the database
db.init_app(app)

# CORS(app)  # comment this on deployment
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '36&462134kjKDhuIS_d23'
app.config.update(
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False,
    SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=False,
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE=None
)

# Initialize Flask-Login
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = request.get_json()
    email = data.get('email')
    password = data.get('password')

    if not email or not password:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Email and password are required'}), 400

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    if not user or not user.check_password(password):
        return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid email or password'}), 401

    login_user(user)
    print('current user: ', current_user)
    print('Authen: ', current_user.is_authenticated)

    return jsonify({'message': 'Login successful'})

@app.route('/get_current_user_id', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def get_current_user_id():
    response = Response(jsonify({'user_id': current_user.id}), 200)
    return response, 200
```

⚠️ By the way I'm serving the frontend from a static folder, which should take care of the CORS policy. My frontend is React, but I used npm run build, to get the static files. that way I don't have to run two separate servers.  **I suspect I'm doing something wrong here*

**Client Side**

apiService.js

```
async function LoginUser(userData) {
  //** User during Sing in */
  const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/login`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      credentials: "include",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(userData),
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Error creating user: ${response.statusText}`);
  }

  return response.json();
}

async function getCurrentUserId() {
  const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/get_current_user_id`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      credentials: "include",
    },
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Error retrieving current user ID: ${response.statusText}`);
  }
  return response;
}
```

**Errors:**

apiService.js:40     GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_current_user_id 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)

on my network tab I see:

Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_current_user_id
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
401 UNAUTHORIZED
Remote Address:
127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Headers:
Accept:
*/*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Type:
application/json
Credentials:
include
Host:
127.0.0.1:5000
Origin:
http://localhost:5000
Referer:
http://localhost:5000/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
cross-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36